# Can not create South database models in Django 1.7

Tags: django, django-south, django-1.7

Django 1.7 has built-in database migration mechanizm. However, I'd like to run South migrations for the ols third-party django apps.

I failed to to 'syncdb' management command with Django 1.7 in order to create South models:

```
/south/management/commands/syncdb.py", line 82, in handle_noargs
old_app_store, cache.app_store = cache.app_store, SortedDict([

AttributeError: 'Apps' object has no attribute 'app_store'
```

Comment: Created south_migrationhistory table with Django 1.6

Comment: Now getting this error on syncdb: /south/hacks/django_1_0.py", line 68, in clear_app_cache
    self.old_app_models, cache.app_models = cache.app_models, {}
AttributeError: 'Apps' object has no attribute 'app_models'

Comment: Any resolution to this? Mysterious.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

On [official South site](http://south.aeracode.org/):

> **South will not work with Django 1.7**; it supports only versions 1.4,
>   1.5 and 1.6.

The only solution I can see is to create django 1.7 for third-party applications within your project using [`MIGRATION_MODULES`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/settings/#std:setting-MIGRATION_MODULES) setting. When these third-party applications will supply django 1.7 migrations. you should remove your migrations and do `migrate --fake` with application migrations.

Comment: I have not tried this solution because the project I needed it for is finished on Django 1.6, but looks like your answer is the closest.

Comment: I was trying to migrate all this time and nothing happened. Thank for you answer!

Answer (score 11):

If you started a project on Django 1.6 but have upgraded to Django 1.7, you may not see this error immediately. But if you then do a fresh checkout and db build for the project, this mysterious error will crop up.

The solution is to remove South from your `INSTALLED_APPS` (and likely pip's `requirements.txt` as well). You don't need them anymore.

Comment: Thank you, I have decided not migrate to Django 1.7 until it is not stable.

Answer (score 2):

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/migrations/#upgrading-from-south

This is part of the stable 1.7 release. You should utilise this process if you're upgrading from 1.6 to 1.7

Comment: Thank you, now that 1.7 release is stable, it is possible. But I was asking about 3d party Django apps I am using in my project. I can't just remove their migrations. Hopefully, the rest of Django community will move on soon.